# Generate data from an arbitrary multivariate continuous density function

Tags: r, simulation, distribution, probability-density

I am trying to sample from a multivariate distribution given by a (quite complex, but continuous) density function in R. For the univariate case I used AbscontDistribution from the distr package, but I cannot make it work for the multivariate case.

I tried finding an appropriate package for this problem online, but cannot find one.
Any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Comment: for normal and  t there is mvtnorm

Comment: Can you please specify from *which* multivariate density you want to sample? You cannot sample from an "arbitrary" distribution, because you need a specific random number generator. Or do you have the density function? Then you can use the rejection method for sampling by means of uniform random samples.

Comment: @cdalitz Yes I have a multivariate density function given. I thought it might be possible to use a built in R package, as rejection method is computational really intense, but maybe there is no such thing...